# SQLite error in QT - QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")

Tags: sql, sqlite, qt

I'm trying to simply count the amount of records that has a 'true' status.

this is the SQLite table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Name varchar(50),Number varchar(15),URL varchar(70),Status bool,ShippingCost integer)
```

I am then calling a query from QT as follows:

```
int SQLiteController::ActiveSupplierCount()
{
    int count = 0;
    QSqlQuery Query;
    Query.prepare("SELECT *"
                  "FROM Suppliers"
                  "WHERE Status = (:Status)");
    Query.bindValue(":Status", true);
    Query.exec();
    qDebug() << Query.lastError();
    while(Query.next() == true)
    {
        count++;
    }
    qDebug() << count;
    return count;
};
```

The last error returned here is "Parameter count mismatch"
and I cannot figure out why... There is only 1 parameter, and I assign to that 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add some extra spaces after each line of your query like this

```
Query.prepare("SELECT * "
              "FROM Suppliers "
              "WHERE Status = (:Status)");
```

Comment: I don't know how or why but this actually fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Because you wrote `SELECT *FROM SuppliersWHERE Status = (:Status)` in your first post which is not valid sql.